# Add JLabel list to JPanel Grid

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I want add JLabel List to JPanel , this is code but dosent work . I think first Loop work correctly and in second Loop dont put JLabel list in Grid . i couldnt run this code in Eclipse

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 640;
    private static final int GRID_ROWS = 20;
    private static final int GRID_COLS = 20;
    private static final int GAP = 1;
    private static final Dimension LAYERED_PANE_SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    private static final Dimension LABEL_SIZE = new Dimension(60, 40);
    private GridLayout gridlayout = new GridLayout(GRID_ROWS, GRID_COLS, GAP, GAP);
    private JPanel backingPanel = new JPanel(gridlayout);
    private JPanel[][] panelGrid = new JPanel[GRID_ROWS][GRID_COLS];


    public DragLabelOnLayeredPane() {
        final List<JLabel> list = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < GRID_ROWS; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < GRID_COLS; c++) {
                int w = bi.getWidth() / GRID_ROWS;
                int h = bi.getHeight() / GRID_COLS;
                BufferedImage b = bi.getSubimage(c * w, r * h, w, h);
                list.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(b))); 
            }
        }
        backingPanel.setSize(LAYERED_PANE_SIZE);
        backingPanel.setLocation(2 * GAP, 2 * GAP);
        backingPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GRID_COLS; col++) {
                panelGrid[row][col] = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                panelGrid[row][col].add(list.get(row));
                gbc.gridx = row; gbc.gridy = col;
                backingPanel.add(panelGrid[row][col], gbc);


            }
        }
```

Comment: We don't know what your program does. So we have no idea what "works" and "doesn't work" mean. You need to do a better job of explaining. And elaborate on the _" i couldnt run this code in Eclipse"_. What does that mean? Are you getting an exception? If so, post the stacktrace. Also in general, for better help, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste-compile-run, so we can test it out

Comment: You say "doesn't work" and "I couldn't run this code". Why? Did you receive any errors? If so, which ones and at which line? Help us help you.

Comment: @justin i dont recieve any error , when i run code i see nothing and reactions

Comment: Instead of `GridBagLayout`, consider using `GridLayout` for rows and columns.